# Change Set Successfully deployed, no changes

Tags: deployment, picklist, change-set

I had made some changes to the picklist values on the "Event" object (which is tied to a global action), and other minor changes. The changes have successfully deployed to the production from the Sandbox, it even has the green success on it by the "Deployed change sets".

However, literally absolutely NOTHING has changes. I selected the correct target org, and production. I added the correct dependencies and profiles to it too. Is this user error or Salesforce error?

EDIT- I removed previous pick list values and replaced them with new ones on this "Event" object. I had changed a page layout for this object as well. This is a standard object as well. I had a connected app on it as well, but that is for another project that I am working on currently, I don't know if this affects it at all. Thats about it.

Comment: We'd need more info as there's a lot that could be missed. I'd suggest an [edit] to your question to include what you actually put into your change set and specify exactly what you changed in the UI.

Comment: if picklist is on a standard field, you need standardvaluesets too

Comment: Where would I put this standardvaluesets? Where can i find this. Sorry ive never heard of it.

Comment: I think it's important to ask which field you're updating picklist values for? Is it a standard field?

Comment: Its the "Subject" field from the "Event" object. This is a basic picklist dropdown. It is a standard field. Is there a way to deploy this using change sets? Or should I just save my ego on wanting to do this through a change set and take the time during work to redo the changes in production? (This is for my job)

Comment: Doesn't look like you can include standardvaluesets in change sets per this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HJ3kAAG). You might have to do this manually if you're not comfortable with using an IDE or a package.xml in workbench.

Comment: Gotcha, LUCKILY the changes aren't too significant so I will go ahead and change them manually in prod. In the future, are there any good tips on dealing with standard objects that you will have to deploy? Thank you